# How can I clear the list of recent connections from Perforce P4V?

Tags: perforce

Perforce P4V keeps a list of recent connections under the menu 'Connections -> Recent Connections'. We have moved our Perforce depot files to a different server so I still have the old connection listed but when it is selected it errors as it can't connect. Is there a way to clear these old connections?

I am using Perforce Visual Client/NTX86/2010.1/271261.

Comment: I haven't found a way to remove those entries in the list. Maybe you should drop support@perforce.com an email?

Comment: Peforce support suggest removing the settings folder (%USERPROFILE%\.p4qt) before starting P4V but this would remove all custom settings (including custom tools).

Comment: @jhwist you can edit ApplicationSettings.xml in .p4qt to edit/remove entries

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you in Linux/Unix?  If so, in your home directory is a `.p4qt/` directory. If Windows, I'm sure you have something similar.

You should have a file called `appsettings.xml` or `ApplicationSettings.xml`.  It should have something like this:

```
 </PropertyList>
 <StringList varName="Recent Connections">
 <String>server:1666, bob, bob_workspace</String>
 <String>server:1666, steve, steve_ws</String>
 <String>server:1666, joe, joe_workspace</String>
 </StringList>
```

Please note, I do not know XML, but you should be able to clear this out of your file.  Or, you can delete this file and have it be recreated if you don't mind some preferences being reset.

Comment: Using Windows the .p4qt/ folder is in the user profile folder. Clearing the outdated connection lines and restarting P4V had the desired result. Perforce support suggested removing the whole directory but said this would remove all settings.

Comment: @Swinders, can you post your note about Windows folders as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

For Mac OS X:

`~/Library/Preferences/com.perforce.p4v/ApplicationSettings.xml`

Answer (score 10):

On Windows7 and P4 2011.1 it's slightly different;

```
%USERPROFILE%\.p4qt\ApplicationSettings.xml
```

You can edit the recent connections in this attribute;

```
<StringList varName="RecentConnections">
    <String>192.168.0.1:1337, Username, Workspacename</String>
    <String>192.168.0.1:1337, Username</String>
</StringList>
```

Answer (score 2):

On windows, the path is `C:\Users\userName\.p4qt\ApplicationSettings.xml`, and you should quit P4V first, then edit the ApplicationSettings.xml, and remove those items in:

```
<StringList varName="RecentConnections">
    <String>192.168.0.1:1337, Username, Workspacename</String>
    <String>192.168.0.1:1337, Username</String>
</StringList>
```

Reopen P4V and you will find the other recent connections is gone...

If you are using the **P4VS** plugin for **Visual Studio**, then you need to open `C:\Users\yourName\AppData\Roaming\Perforce\P4VS\LocalSettings.ini`

Delete the other items in:

```
<RecentConnections maxCapacity="5" type="Perforce.P4VS.MRUList">
    <RecentConnections type="Perforce.P4VS.ConnectionData">
            <ServerPort type="string">192.168.0.1:1337</ServerPort>
            <UserName type="string">yourUserName</UserName>
            <Workspace type="string">yourWorkSpace</Workspace>
    </RecentConnections>
    <RecentConnections type="Perforce.P4VS.ConnectionData">
            <ServerPort type="string">192.168.0.2:1337</ServerPort>
            <UserName type="string">yourUserName2</UserName>
            <Workspace type="string">yourWorkSpace2</Workspace>
    </RecentConnections>
    <RecentConnections type="null"/>
    <RecentConnections type="null"/>
    <RecentConnections type="null"/>
</RecentConnections>
```

Now, its clean...

Answer (score 1):

In Later versions of Perforce (at least `Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2012.1/500245`) the files is stored in

```
{UserProfileFolder}\.p4qt\ApplicationSettings.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Peforce support suggest removing the settings folder (%USERPROFILE%.p4qt) before starting P4V but this would remove all custom settings (including custom tools).

Using Windows the .p4qt/ folder is in the user profile folder.

Clearing the outdated connection lines and restarting P4V had the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT delete the entire folder!!!

For windows, go to: %USERPROFILE%.p4qt\0001Clients\WorkspaceSettings.xml

Then you will find some items:

```
<StringList varName="RecentlyUsedWorkspaces">
    <String>workspace1.test</String>    
    <String>workspace2.test</String>
    <String>workspace3.test</String>
    <String>workspace4.test</String>
 </StringList>
```

You can delete from this list.