# Perforce - Disable storing a list of recent connections

Tags: perforce

Perforce (P4V) allows you to configure your favourite connections, aliasing ips/ports/workspaces to a more memorable name. However after visiting each favourite it will then be added to the "recent connections" list, thus the dialog has 2 entries for the same connection:

[image: screenshot]

Ideally it would not add an existing Favourite to recent-connections, but failing that, is it possible to turn off recent-connections entirely?

(Similar to but not a duplicate of "[How can I clear the list of recent connections from Perforce P4V?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316173/how-can-i-clear-the-list-of-recent-connections-from-perforce-p4v)").

Comment: P4V Recent Connections stores only the last five connections that the user has connected to solve the problem of having a lot of connections
that are seldom used stored under the recent connections.  For users who
want a list of more than 5 connections, there’s the Favorite connections feature.  Do you want a way to delete or clear stored connections in the list? Or do you moreso want the Open Connection dialog to not show both the Recent and Favorite connections?

Comment: Thanks for fast response. I'd like it not to show the recent connections at all. (Or never populate it with connections that already exist in favourites).

Comment: You're welcome. I filed an enhancement request on your behalf for the P4V Open Connection dialog to not display duplicates between the Recent and Favorite connections.

Comment: For reference, these are all stored in XML config files under your "home" dir (varies by O/S). It is possible to update the relevant file and remove the entries via a script or similar if you really want to get rid of things.